# Socket.io - websocket connection invalid

Tags: java, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a Java software that connects to Socket.io websocket, and it was working fine. Until now. 
My server now starts to trigger this error when I try to conect to it (Only from Java. Browsers still normal):

```
warn: websocket connection invalid
```

So, I try to create a new server with the same configs that the first one, and run the same code. Works fine.
I dont know where to look to solve this.

Anyone have some clue?

Thanks very much.

Comment: We can't guess what is in your code that gives the error. Please post minimal code to reproduce the error.

Comment: It isn`t the code. It just basics Socket.io service, and whatever I code, still get error. I was thinking about some server configuration.